# Play Framework: "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, scala, playframework

With a basically default setup of Play 2 I'm getting this error within my templates. I'm not quite sure what could be causing it. The asset reference is correct, I tried using a CDN instead and disabling all other scripts but I still can't get jquery to work.

routes:

```
# Routes
# This file defines all application routes (Higher priority routes first)
# ~~~~

# Home page
GET     /                                       @controllers.Application.index

# Projects
GET     /new                                    @controllers.Projects.create
GET     /new/upload                             @controllers.Projects.upload

GET     /:author                                @controllers.Projects.showAuthor(author)

GET     /:author/:name                          @controllers.Projects.show(author, name)
GET     /:author/:name/versions                 @controllers.Projects.showVersions(author, name)
GET     /:author/:name/dicuss                   @controllers.Projects.showDiscussion(author, name)

# RESTful API
# TODO: Ensure no one can be named "api"
GET     /api/:version/projects                  @controllers.Api.listProjects(version)

# Map static resources from the /public folder to the /assets URL path
GET     /assets/*file                           controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

Base layout:

```
@*
Base layout template for website. Most templates within the project will extend
this.
*@
@(title: String)(content: Html)

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>@title</title>

        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="https://cdn.spongepowered.org/uploads/default/original/2X/9/9ba706a80e45cf427617525ee2a19fad7bb6b109.png">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="@routes.Assets.at("bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css")" />
            <!-- This is probably bad -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://forums-cdn.spongepowered.org/stylesheets/desktop_52268f077fc3c24a38a9bece28bbb8e6ae598120.css"/>
            <!-------------------------->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="@routes.Assets.at("stylesheets/main.css")" />

        <script type="javascript" src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/jquery-1.9.0.min.js")"></script>
        <script type="javascript" src="@routes.Assets.at("bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js")"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            $(function() { // <- error here
                alert("hello");
            });
        </script>
        @core.header()
        @content
    </body>
</html>
```

Any help figuring this out is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: did you check to see your network tab ? I guess `"@routes.Assets.at` is causing a 404

Comment: Network tab reports a 304 for jquery

Comment: Could you clean browser cache and see network tab again?

Comment: I figured it out actually, should have used `text/javascript` not `javascript` *facepalms*